Numering page with abntex2
I'm having trouble trying to numbering the pages. Why is the page number not appearing on the 'Introduction' page in the provided LaTeX code?
\documentclass[12pt,        
oneside,            
a4paper,        
chapter=TITLE,      
section=TITLE,      
english,        
brazil          
]{abntex2}



\begin{document}
    

    
\tableofcontents*
    
    
\chapter{Introduction}
\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter{Literature Review} 

Despite the studies present above, none of them...
    
    
    
\end{document}      
    

    

I want to numbering introduction as the first page, but I can't get this output:


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to TeX.SE.  You have a lot of code here, not all of which is related to your problem.  Could you delete out the unrelated bits?  And add two more lines at the end so that it produces some valid output?  Often, the first page will be numbered differently than the rest.  Are you wanting arabic on all of them?

That's still a lot of unnecessary code.  You have \pagestyle{myheadings}, but I'm not seeing where you have done anything related to myheadings.

your code should be an example of the problem  it is an incomplete document so produces no output and has many tens of lines that are clearly unrelated, you are asking about the first page so remove all the code setting up floats and caption setc and almost all the packages as they are clearly not involved, then check that it makes a small one or two page document that shows the problem you have.

Off-topic: If you want to use Latin Modern (text and math) fonts, you should execute \usepackage{lmodern} -- as well as get rid of the instruction \usepackage{times} entirely.

thanks for the feeback. Get rid of a lot of code, I hope is better now.

The problem is that your code can't possibly create your image: it doesn't have \end{document}, and doesn't have "Despite all of the studies present above, none of them ...".  So we can give you code that would make a number appear for this code, but that won't help you, because your code is different than this code.  You can actually trim this down to 6 lines of code, at which point you can discover that \pagestyle{plain} before \begin{document} doesn't give what you want, but swapping their order does.

I've already change the code and use \pagestyle{plain} after but did not work

You still haven't shown us code that corresponds to your image (and have gotten rid of too much code), but now you've told us you're using \chapter.  Have you tried \thispagestyle{plain} after the chapter command?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem. I you add screenshots, they should show either what you get from the shown code (and be used to explain the problem with that code), or they should show what you expect (and therefore illustrate the requested result).

@Teepeemm already tried after the chapter but didn't work. I'll change the code to what the image shows...

It's not clear to me that you've tried \*this*pagestyle{plain} after the \chapter.  And you still haven't provided code that produces the image you've shown us.

now I get it @Teepeemm, thanks! I fixed the code to appear what the image shows!

The abntex2 class by design doesn't print page numbers in the chapter start pages.
You can override the behavior.
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  oneside,
  a4paper,
  chapter=TITLE,
  section=TITLE,
  english,
  brazil,
]{abntex2}

\AtBeginDocument{\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{plain}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Literature Review}

Despite the studies present above, none of them...

\end{document}


